# Kubernetes ingress service should be LoadBalancer or NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this application I'm toying with. It consists of a `Deployment` (`web` with 3 instances running) with a `Service` exposing it (`web-service`). Right now the `Service` is of type `LoadBalancer`. I also added a `Ingress` directive to route my traffic as desired.

My question is...with the `Ingress` in place, should I switch the service type from `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort` or I should leave it in the same state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation I have read so far it seems to be the general concensus to avoid `nodePort` as it is allocating ports on the physical (or virtual) nodes and that can become crowded after a time. Having a `LoadBalancer` automatically exposes a free port that the Google L3 Loadbalancer routes traffic to so no need to switch this to Nodeport.

Also note - once you have a working Ingress you don't need to expose the backend service as a `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort` at all - a normal internal `kind: Service` is enough to receive traffic from the `Ingress`.

Comment: I have been unable to get `Ingress` to work consistently with `Service`. If I omit `NodePort` in my service definition and let the default kick in, I keep getting a `404` when hitting the public static IP of my `Ingress`

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44521) and described [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_2_expose_nginx_as_a_service), the service needs to be `NodePort`