# Use of Ingress with service of type LoadBalancer on Kind

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, nginx-ingress, kind

I had found a definition, when reviewing a project, that intrigued me: the use of Ingress with a Service of type LoadBalancer without installing the load balancer itself on [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/loadbalancer/). As defined, it seems to work but I don't know why. I say that it works because I'm able to curl the application on browser as expected.

Code:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server
  labels:
    app: server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: server
        image: localhost:5000/server:2.0
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: server
  name: server
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: server
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: server
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: server
            port:
              number: 8080
```

I thought that hitting a Ingress and then the LoadBalancer would cause some redirect issue. My choice for that case would be a simple ClusterIP instead, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41565042/6328506) answer agrees. **If MetalLB is not installed on the cluster, what the LoadBalancer do here?** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69230856/6328506) may have a point for wanting something like that, but as far as I know, the load balancer by itself is a resource outside the cluster, i.e: a cloud provider load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

> If MetalLB is not installed on the cluster, what the LoadBalancer do
> here?

**MetalLB** is the `load-balancer` implementation for **bare metal** **Kubernetes** clusters. So MetaLB comes into the picture if you are on the baremetal or so.

If you are on managed could **LoadBalancer** will get auto-created if you will mention into **YAML** config without MetalLB.

> what the LoadBalancer do here?

Since it mentioned in YAML config LoadBalancer will get created for that service.

Yes, you can use the **ClusterIP** instead of creating the **LoadBalancer** service. Change type and remove from the service.

Ideal **traffic** flow goes like

```
Internet > LoadBalancer > Ingress > ingress controller (Backend) > service > deployment > Pods > container
```

Yes, LB is resource of **CloudProvider** if you are using any managed.

Comment: I think you mean "managed cloud" when you say "If you are on managed could LoadBalancer will get auto-created if you will mention into YAML config without MetalLB". Anyway, your explanation was clear to me. Thank you. What I don't get yet is how Load Balancer works in that case without MetalLB or something similar. The app was deployed on Kind, not in a cloud service